# React - Native IOS/Android Simulator problem

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm currently building my first app using react-native. As I'm trying to run the simulator for both, IOS and Android, I run into errors. When I try running the simulator for IOS, using 'npm run ios', it runs the simulator successfully, but when I try to make changes in the App.js, they don't appear in the simulator menu...I tried restarting the simulator several times but it didn't work, I'm also not able to use commands within the simulator, such as 'cmd+R' to reload, even if there is no error message.
When It comes to Android, I can't even run the simulator (using 'npm run android') and I always run into the following error message:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! feedIt@0.0.1
> android: `react-native run-android` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the feedIt@0.0.1 android script. npm ERR! This is
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/maurice/.npm/_logs/2020-07-13T08_19_29_328Z-debug.log
> Maurices-MacBook-Air:myApp maurice$

Here's my App.js:

```
/**  * Sample React Native App  *
https://github.com/facebook/react-native  *  * @format  * @flow
strict-local  */

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>{/* Rest of your app code */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next!
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

I can't fix the problem and hope for any help.
Regards,
Maurice

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next!
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

You had defined your `App` component twice. And you also had some duplicate/contradicting imports.

Comment: Apparently that doesn't work, trying to run the Android emulator leads into the same problem. Running the IOS Simulator leads into another new problem, which displays an error message within the simulator. I link a screenshot below.
Thanks for the answer,
Maurice

Comment: The error in the image you posted means that you haven't installed `react-native-gesture-handler`. So this doesn't mean the code doesn't work.

Comment: I installed react-native-gesture-handler, but when I did this and tried to run the IOS Simulator, I got the same problem as I get with running the Android Emulator, which is that I run into the error message, which I linked in my first post.

Comment: In case of iOS make sure you have installed the `pods` also try to restart the packager and run the build again. If that doesn't work try the steps that are listed in the error message.

Comment: CocoaPods are installed and restarting also doesn't work. There are no steps to solve the problem within the error message, but I found something interesting, which maybe could help solving the problem.
The error message says:

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.5.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods')

Comment: I meant the steps in the error in the image you posted. 1. Clear watchman watches 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install 3. Reset Metro's cache 4. Remove the cache.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the error message within the simulator, but now the changes I make in the App.js, are still not displayed in the Simulator...really don't know why this happens ) :
Trying to run the Android Emulator still leads into an error message